# Three endorsements before solo?

Tags: logbook-endorsements

Before a solo flight is allowed for a student pilot, what endorsements are required in continental USA?

Thank you!

Comment: This looks like information that could be found rather easily on google

Comment: Or in the FAR/AIM in the US.

Comment: You don't specify jurisdiction, but in the US, 14 CFR 61.87(n) specifies only one logbook endorsement required for a student to solo.

Comment: This sounds like quiz time, with the question based on an unassailable statement of fact.  If you have knowledge that 3 are required then cite your source.  Otherwise I agree with Gerry that only 1 is required.  (The question could be improved by simply asking "if" 3 are required...)

Comment: P.S.  Most flight schools will have a stage check, with a second opinion endorsement by another CFI, but this doesn't mean that it is an FAA requirement to have multiple endorsements.

Comment: Eenie, meenie, mynie...  if four were required, we could also bring in moe.

Comment: When you ask about regulations, please *always* tell us which country you're asking about. Even if it seems obvious to you, it may not be to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer will pertain to your first (presumably) local solo. You will need the following endorsements:

1. TSA Citizenship Verification: Title 49 CFR Part 1552.3(h)
2. Pre-Solo Aeronautical Knowledge: Title 14 CFR Part 61.87(b, c, & d)
3. Pre-Solo 90 day (local flight and limitations): Title 14 CFR Part 61.87(n)

Comment: @Michael Hall - Darn it. I meant to phrase those in the form of a question, Alex. 

Comment: Item 1 should be 49 CFR 1552.3(h) for "U.S. citizens and nationals and Department of Defense endorsees."  It requires the student to provide the documentation and sub paragraph (i) requires the school to maintain a copy for 5 years.  It does not specify a logbook endorsement.

Comment: @Gerry - thanks. Changed 14 to 49. I received two in my logbook. One from a fixed wing school and one from an rotary wing school unaffiliated with the fixed wing school. I’ll have to look up the actual Reg.

Comment: The knowledge test and training in 61.87(b...m) must be documented (written test, flight training logged) but there's no separate endorsement required. The instructor must verify it before providing the endorsement specified in (n) or (m) (for night solo). I actually had several endorsements, but they were driven by school policy. The first had wind, crosswind, visibility and 'local area' restrictions.  Later endorsements raised the limits.

Comment: @DeanF.  *49 CFR Part 1552.3(h)* only pertains to flight schools, not private instructors.

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement for multiple endorsements.  Title 14 CFR 61.87 spells out the requirements for student solo flight.  There are many requirements, but the question was  about endorsements.

61.87(p)(4) is the only part of this section that specifically addresses endorsements, and it says:

> (p) Limitations on flight instructors authorizing solo flight. No instructor may authorize a student pilot to perform a solo flight unless that instructor has -
>
> (4) Endorsed the student pilot's logbook for the specific make and model aircraft to be flown, and that endorsement remains current for solo flight privileges, provided an authorized instructor updates the student's logbook every 90 days thereafter.

As long as the CFI verifies all requirements of the section are met, only one safe-for-solo logbook endorsement is needed.